# How put each array value into text-field in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, textbox, tostring, settext

I tried to put array values into separate textfields. IDE indicates code is always gone wrong. There are 6 text fields and 6 values in the array. So I need that 6 array values put into textfields. Check my code and help me correct it.
**(This array is Integer one)**

```
import java.util.Arrays   
.
...

numO1.setText(Arrays.toString(Isortarray[0]));
numO2.setText(Arrays.toString(Isortarray[1]));
numO3.setText(Arrays.toString(Isortarray[2]));
numO4.setText(Arrays.toString(Isortarray[3]));
numO5.setText(Arrays.toString(Isortarray[4]));
numO6.setText(Arrays.toString(Isortarray[5]));
```

Comment: If `Isortarray` is an array of strings, `Isortarray[x]` will be a `String`, so calling `Arrays.toString()` is unnecessary.

Comment: `numO1.setText(Isortarray[0].toString());`

Comment: I would definitely use a `for` loop here, and make your 6 text fields part of an array instead of using numbered variables. I also recommend using a `List` over an array, even if it's just via `Arrays.asList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you :)

```
numO1.setText(String.valueOf(Isortarray[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

It's a 1D string array

From what you provided it appears your problem is at Arrays.toString.
When you use Isortarray[3] it should provide the string you need.

Calling Arrays.toString on a single string will cause unexpected results. So simply remove the arrays.toString call.

Answer (score 0):

dynamically and assuming your array is String

```
    String[] Isortarray = new String[]{"1","2","3","4","5","6"};

     //Assign me JTextfield create and name and value dynamically
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            JTextField txt = new JTextField(Isortarray[i]);
            txt.setName("txt"+i);
            frm.add(txt);
            frm.validate();
            frm.repaint();
        }
```